# Using events to communicate between models in backbone

Tags: events, model, backbone.js

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this is not working. I have two models in Backbone that I want to decouple by moving to an evented setup. It's easier to just show you:

```
var Session = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/some/url/session.js',
    initialize: function(credentials) {
        if (this.isValid() == true) {
            this.trigger("start");
        }
    },
    validate: function() {
        if (this.get("user") != "user" || this.get("password") != "pass") {
            this.trigger("end");
            return "Invalid credentials.";
        }
    }
});

var MainModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/some/url/config.js',
    initialize: function(credentials) {
        this.session = new Session(credentials);
        this.session.on("start", this.start());
        this.session.on("end", this.end());
    },
    end: function() {
        console.debug("session ended");
    },
    start: function() {
        console.debug("session started");
    }
});


new MainModel({
  "user":"user",
  "password": "pass"
});
```

The problem I'm seeing is that both MainModel.start() and MainModel.end() are being triggered all the time immediately after instantiation. I don't know if I'm adding the listeners correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fguillen is correct, you need to bind the function `this.start` and not the result of the function call.

Additionally, the order of your bindings is also incorrect. You are validating the user in `Session.intialize`, but at this point, the bindings are not yet created. I would suggest to add a separate `login()`function, which is called after you bind your events:

```
var Session = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/some/url/session.js',
    login: function(credentials) {
        if (this.isValid() == true) {
            this.trigger("start");
        }
    },
    validate: function() {
        if (this.get("user") != "user" || this.get("password") != "pass") {
            this.trigger("end");
            return "Invalid credentials.";
        }
    }
});

var MainModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/some/url/config.js',
    initialize: function(credentials) {
        this.session = new Session(credentials);    
        this.session.on("start", this.start);
        this.session.on("end", this.end);
        this.session.login();    
    },
    end: function() {
        console.debug("session ended");
    },
    start: function() {
        console.debug("session started");
    }
});


new MainModel({
    "user":"user",
    "password": "pass"
});
```

Working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mbuchetics/Ujh72/3/

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I thought there could've been some sort of race condition there but couldn't figure it out. I removed the parenthesis from the start and end methods and created the login method as suggested. Works as it should. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. you have a typo:

Instead of this:

```
this.session.on("start", this.start());
```

Use this:

```
this.session.on("start", this.start);
```

In the first case you are executing the function `start()` and adding the `return` of this function as a callback, in the second case you are adding a *reference* to the function to be the callback, which is what you want.

Actually I'd use this:

```
this.session.on("start", this.start, this);
```

To send a correct *binding* to the execution of `this.start()`.. but this is another story :)